# JetBrains IDE. Custom pattern to highlight (Not comments like todos)

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to highlight e.g. `private` with red background, `public` with green background without changing color scheme. Plugins, built-in tools?

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5473 (and linked tickets for language/specific cases) -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

**P.S.** Related  ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7247 (already linked in the aforementioned ticket anyway) -- this one is more generic .. and less chances to be implemented.